# iterating through each value in the column and comparing them with the other values in other columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops

I am working on, going into each element of each column and comparing them with every other element of the other column in the dataframe.

To do this I made 4 loops (nested) and tried to test it but apparently, it is very very very slow. Is there any other way through which I can do it?
Here is my code:

```
num = 0
for i in df:
   for k in df:
      for val in df[i]:
           for val2 in df[k]:
                 if val == val2:
                    num += 1
                 else:
                    break
```

It is just to count the common elements but that is not my main purpose, it's just to know is there an efficient way to do it?

For Example:

[image: Don't mind my drawing!]

So I want to find edit distance between each value in a column with the same index value of every other column but all that I could find is finding distances for all the values in the column from all the values in the other columns which is quite slow.

Better understanding is shown in the pic but I want the one with the 'tick sign' on it. And I want an average distance of the newly made columns.

Output:

```
Average Distance between column1 and column2 is (some num) , 
 
Average Distance between column1 and column3 is (some num)
```

Thanks a ton!

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow!   please review the guidelines in submitting question here  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you provide a sample DataFrame with your expected output, I'm sure you will get a much more efficient way to do this comparison

Comment: It is edited so i hope now my question is a bit clear?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for, I had to create some of my own data, but I believe this is what yo u are trying to accomplish

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1' : ['Yes'],
    'Column2' : ['No'],
    'Column3' : ['Yes'],
    'Column4' : ['Yes']
})

df['Count'] = df.apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x), axis = 1).apply(lambda x : x.split()).apply(lambda x : x.count('Yes'))
```